# Serialize from actionlistener

Tags: java, swing, serialization

I'm trying to serialize all of my objects when the user clicks on the File menu save command.
If I'm understanding correctly, the `defaultReadObject()` and `defaultWriteObject()` saves all of my objects except from static members so I tried to use these. My program is a kind of graph drawing program. It has a control frame where the user can set up the algorithm to run, and an other frame where the graph is painted.The the user can click on a next and previous button to see which nodes the algorithm is going through. So I'd like to save the actual state of the drawing so the user can continue the stepping after exit.
I've read that the `defaultWriteObject` should be called from the `writeObject` method but my problem is I don´t know how can I save the instance of the Control and Draw2 class from the actionlistener, which are created in the main function?
The relevant part of my code:

```
public class Control extends JPanel implements Serializable{

private String sourceFolder;
private String selectedAlg;
public List<Node> nodeList;
private JMenuBar jMenuBar;
private JMenu jMenu;
private JMenuItem jMenuItem;
private Draw2 draw;
private Search s;
//...
//and a lot more variables

void createControl(JFrame f, Draw2 d){
    jMenuBar = new JMenuBar();
    jMenu = new JMenu();
    jMenuItem = new JMenuItem();

    jMenu.setText("File");
    jMenuBar.add(jMenu);

    jMenuItem.setText("Save");
    jMenuItem.addActionListener(new SaveAction());

    jMenu.add(jMenuItem);

    //building the control window with textfields, buttons..

    draw=d;
    s=new Search();
}

private void writeObject( ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {

      out.defaultWriteObject();
}

//inner class, actionlistener for save menuItem
public class SaveAction implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        try {
            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("savedfile");
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(f);

            //So how can save the instance of control and draw class
 //here, which is created in the main function? 
//how to call writeObject and with what parameter?

        } catch (IOException o) {   
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Control");
    JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Draw");

    Control cont = new control();
    Draw2 gp = new Draw2(cont);

    cont.createControl(frame, gp);

    frame.setJMenuBar(cont.jMenuBar);
    gp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0,0));
    //Control Frame
    frame.setSize(800,330);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(cont, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    //Drawing Frame
    frame2.setSize(800,600);
    frame2.setLocation(0, 330);
    frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   
    frame2.add(gp);
    frame2.setVisible(true);        

}

}

public class Draw2 extends JPanel implements Serializable{

     public boolean toDraw = false;
     public boolean timedDraw = false;
     public boolean steppedDraw = false;
     private control c;

    public Draw2(control co){
        c=co;
    }
    public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {   
    //drawing the graph
    }
}
```

And one last question. When I load the object from the saved file how can I replace the running object to the loaded object? I thought about doing it through a paramater but actionPerformed cannot have a parameter besides ActionEvent.

```
 public class LoadAction implements ActionListener{

       Control contr;

      public LoadAction(Control control) {
           contr = control;
      }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        try {
            FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream("savedfile");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(f);
            contr= (Control)in.readObject();
           //so now I have the loaded object in the contr object, 
           //but How can copy it over the current object?
            in.close();

            System.out.println(contr.aktIndex);
        } catch (IOException o) {
            o.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  And as an aside, generally only 1 frame should be created per application.  The rest would usually be dialogs or option panes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend action listener and pass the handle of the object to be saved to this action listener in the constructor.

You could move the object to be saved a class variable to do this.

```
public class SaveAction extends ActionListener {

  Control control;

  public SaveAction(Control control) {
    this.control = control;
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // your save code here
  }

}
```

and then pass control when you new SaveAction in your code above...

```
new SaveAction(this);
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me, but could you be more specific because I don't really understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you very much, the saving is working perfectly now, but I have one last question about loading. I editet my post and appended my question to the end.

Comment: Do the same as SaveAction. Pass the reference of Control object in the constructor of LoadAction.

Comment: Sorry if i misunderstand something but I tried that. Editet my post again with the constructor, but like this i copy over the current object to the cont variable and when the actionPerformed method changes it, it changes the contr variable and it has no effect on the "running object".

Comment: You cannot replace the original object but either you can copy contents into it manually or you can place the load action outside the  class and replace with new object when you load - so the old will be disposed and replace with new. so you replace old Control object with a new one in the container for this Control. this can be done using an inner class with a shared class variable accessible in this action, if that makes sense.